# Convert and merge strings into a list in Python

Tags: python, string, list

In Python I have four strings that include the formatting of a list:

```
line1 ="['a.b.c','b.c.a','c.d.e']"
line2 ="['def','efg']"
line3 ="['f']"
line4 ="['g']"
```

How do I merge them all so I get a valid Python list such as:

```
SumLine = ['a.b.c','b.c.a','c.d.e','def','efg','f','g']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple way is to concetenate the strings to an expression that can be evaulated to give the required result:

```
line1 ="['a.b.c','b.c.a','c.d.e']"
line2 ="['def','efg']"
line3 ="['f']"
line4 ="['g']"
lines = [line1, line2, line3, line4]

print eval('+'.join(lines))
```

However this is unsafe if you can't trust your input, so if you're using Python 2.6 or higher you should use the safe eval function `ast.literal_eval` in the ast module, although this doesn't work with the '+' trick so you will have to iterate over each element instead.

Comment: @Zach, yep, this gives `ValueError: malformed string`.  Wouldn't it be nice if people minimally tried answers out before accepting them?-)

Comment: I guess he chose the plain 'eval' version. I removed the incorrect code for the literal_eval.

Answer (score 11):

```
import ast

line1 ="['a.b.c','b.c.a','c.d.e']"
line2 ="['def','efg']"
line3 ="['f']"
line4 ="['g']"

SumLine = []

for x in (line1, line2, line3, line4):
  SumLine.extend(ast.literal_eval(x))

print SumLine
```

Don't use the built-in `eval` unless you have preternatural trust in the strings you're evaluating; `ast.literal_eval`, while limited to simple constants, is totally safe and therefore, most often, way preferable.

Comment: Note that the ast module is only available in Python 2.6 and higher.

Comment: @Zach, yep, 2.5 has `_ast` but that's lower level and thus harder to work with.

Answer (score 1):

Try [eval](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html?highlight=eval#eval):

```
>>> line1 ="['a.b.c','b.c.a','c.d.e']"
>>> line2 ="['def','efg']"
>>> line3 ="['f']"
>>> line4 ="['g']"
>>> eval(line1) + eval(line2) + eval(line3) + eval(line4)
['a.b.c', 'b.c.a', 'c.d.e', 'def', 'efg', 'f', 'g']
```

But be careful, because `eval` can be dangerous.  Don't use it on input that you receive from the user and haven't validated.

Answer (score 1):

The quick and dirty way is to use `eval`:

```
SumLine = eval(line1) + eval(line2) + eval(line3) + eval(line4)
```

But dont do this if you are getting these strings from someone else (ie user input)

Answer (score 1):

Where did you get these strings? Anything short of a real parser will be fragile. Below is what I would recommed, if I had not seen Alex Martelli's brilliant answer before!

You may parse them as JSON arrays, but JSON wants to read double-quoted strings, not single quotes. This introduces fragility to the method, but still much preferable to `eval()` which is unsafe.

```
import json
line1 ="['a.b.c','b.c.a','c.d.e']"
json.loads(line1.replace("'", '"'))
```

The result is a parsed list like `[u'a.b.c', u'b.c.a', u'c.d.e']`, you may than go on to join the parsed lists.

Comment: I hope you don't have any escaped single-quotes in the middle of those strings, or you'll be affecting the content too... bug!

Answer (score 0):

you need to `eval` them first and then you could sum the results. But I wonder how do you get this strings in the first place?